# Convert String to ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, utf-8, iso-8859-1

In my JavaScript app, I want to give the user a button to download data in either UTF-8 or in ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1).

The only working solution I have found so far is using iconv-lite.

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
iconv.encode(utf8String, 'iso-8859-1');
```

However the library is very large and I would be happy to have a smaller solution.
Do you have any idea how to achieve that or get only the relevant part from iconv-lite?

Here is what I've tried so far:

**Using TextEncoder**

```
var utf8Array = new TextEncoder().encode(utf8String);
var iso88591String = new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1").decode(utf8Array);
```

I still get an UTF-8 String as a result.

**Using escape**

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(utf8String));
```

Throws an error "malformed URI"

**Lib Utf**
form here: https://github.com/DesWurstes/utf.js

```
console.log(ToString(FromUTF8(utf8)));
```

Returns binary data.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to get as output? It would have to be an `ArrayBuffer` or a base 64 encoded string or such…?!

Comment: IIRC, LATIN1 occupies the first 256 code points of UTF16, the encoding used by JavaScript. So provided the text only contains codepoints <= 255, I would treat it as a binary string (of 8 bit values) and attempt to convert it to a Blob for downloading. Converting utf-8 text to UTF16 (a JavaScript string) would depend on where the text came from.

Comment: @deceze I expect a String in ISO8859-1 format.

Comment: What does that mean exactly?! *Javascript strings* are always UTF-16 encoded. You can't have a Javascript string which is Latin-1 encoded, because that's not a Javascript string. If you want Latin-1 bytes representing some text, you'll need them in some form that can be expressed in Javascript, which would be a buffer or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @deceze for your help. Maybe this fiddle helps to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/7jsfce6v/
However I don't get it working with iconv-lite support because of the missing support for "require".

Comment: @kirschkern Were you able to get this fixed? I got here having found the same results as you. I particularly am weirded out that the suggestion to use Encoder is supposed to work but as you, I get an UTF-8 encoded string instead of an ISO-8859-1 encoded string (I know the type "string" in JavaScript is only UTF16 but for the context of the question the request was clear, even if the output is not a javascript string but just an ISO8859-1 -encoded string).

Comment: @Eduo No. I ended up using iconv-lite `var iconv = require('iconv-lite'); iconv.encode(utf8String, 'iso-8859-1');`